# How to use remote function in different server

Tags: php

Im trying to use function that i put in remote server

Now in testing stage, im doing this in my local server (MAMP)

I already enabled allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include in php.ini file

in remote.php (in remote server), i have this code for testing :

```
function test(){
echo 'testing calling remote function';
}
```

and in my local server, i have this code :

```
require_once('http://remoteserver.com/remote.php')

test(); // calling test function in remote.php
```

but all i got is error call to undefined function

am i doing this in right way or wrong way ?

is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `require_once('http://remoteserver.com/remote.php')`, the content you included is the output of `http://remoteserver.com/remote.php`, not the php source of this script.

Comment: so, basically i cannot call the function inside remote file?

Comment: Yep, unless you can let the romote server echo out the php source.

Comment: oh i see..
so that means, this method only can be use to echo content in the remote file.
now i understand. :)